# encodeURIComponent does not return encoded URI

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, browser, bookmarklet

I would like to create a bookmarklet that appends the url of the current page to another predefined url.

```
javascript:(function(){location.href='example.com/u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)}());
```

However, the returned url is not encoded, but when I tried `encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(location.href))` it worked. I don't understand why doubling encodeURIComponent makes the different?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var href = (a) => {return 'example.com/u='+encodeURIComponent(a)}
```

and call `href` to get encoded url.

```
var encoded_url = href(location.href)
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to complicate things, just to understand why I needed to double 'encodeURIComponent' to get it to work.

Comment: Not sure about that, mine working with single `encodeURIComponent`. Can you add little more info, how you are creating your bookmarklet?

Comment: I'm actually using the bookmarklet mentioned here: http://youtube4kdownloader.com/en5/bookmarklet.html
and see them using double `encodeURIComponent`. It worked when you left it that way, but not when you removed one `encodeURIComponent`. You can use that bookmarklet on a YouTube video to see what I mean.